# webpack & typescript: partial lodash import with es5 as target not working

Tags: typescript, import, webpack, bundle

I am trying to get partial imports of lodash to work in a webpack / typescript / react environment to reduce the bundle size. I am using `lodash@4.17.4` and `webpack@2.4.1`

I know I should not import lodash like this, as it imports the whole lodash library:

```
import * as lodash from 'lodash';
 lodash.clone({});
```

So I tried this:

```
import { clone, create } from 'lodash';
```

But this still keeps importing the whole library and not only the functions I need (bundlesize does not change). 
So I read a bit and saw this:

```
import clone = require('lodash/clone');
```

This actually worked, only the functions I needed get imported and my bundlesize is a few hundred KB smaller. But unfortunately typescript gives me the following error (error is displayed only when building the bundle, when running the watch / webDev-Server everything is fine):

```
Import assignment cannot be used when targeting ECMAScript 2015 modules. Consider using 'import * as ns from "mod"', 'import {a} from "mod"', 'import d from "mod"', or another module format instead.
```

Is this because I got `"target":"es5"` in my typescript config? And if so, how can I still achieve partial imports with es5 modules as target?

My typescript config looks like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "jsx": "react",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noImplicitReturns": false,
    "removeComments": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "outDir": "build",
    "lib": [
      "es6",
      "es7",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "dist",
    "build",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components"
  ]
}
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**
When I do just a regular require:

```
const clone = require('lodash/clone');
```

everything compiles without errors (the watch and the build). Is that the correct way to import the latest version of lodash? It seems wrong

Comment: What version of lodash are you using?

Comment: I am using `lodash@4.17.4`

Answer (score 0):

That's I import lodash

```
import { clone } from 'lodash/clone'
```

Comment: Hey thanks, but I already got types installed for lodash. So that cannot be the problem ( I also updated them).

Comment: Have you tried to turn off `noImplicitAny`? That's my config and it works https://github.com/ematipico/typescript-sample/blob/master/tsconfig.json